# Mathematical comparison of various image enhancement techniques on an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I want know what could be the various ways to compare the same image enhanced by various image enhancement techniques not visually but mathematically?

For example: (i) May be (I am not sure) one could look at their histograms and calculate the variance of them. One with the highest variance might be the best technique? or

(ii) Randomly, pick a local region in all the enhanced images and compute again variance or  look at the difference of the max. and min. values of that local region. One with highest variance or difference might be the best?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Setting the image to binary (0/255) will maximize the variance but it won't have the best quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the sort of enhancement you are looking at.

For example, for the likes of denoising and deblurring, the PSNR and MSE might be appropriate, especially when you have access to groundtruth images which you can compare the enhanced image against.

Aesthetic enhancement on the other hand might be harder to quantify as it requires a certain degree of subjectivity. A highly cited work in this area is:
[Studying Aesthetic in Photographic Images Using a Computational Approach](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/~wangz/project/imsearch/Aesthetics/ECCV06/datta.pdf&ei=ar3oUYPPN4zQrQeP4IHYAg&usg=AFQjCNHqStt3Fhfpg-ykwvnTVVluYgJ_vw&sig2=35vORcs0RfhtnfVWEX2OlA&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bmk)
You can check out the citations therein for relevant references.

Answer (score 1):

Two common metrics for comparing images are [mean square error (MSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) and [peak signal to noise ratio (PSNR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio).